# Network Map from multiple columns?

Tags: r, d3.js, graphics, mapping, igraph

I have a list of table names and wanted to be able to visualize their relationships in R. So a line going from table A to

So for example, if i had a dataframe:

```
 Col 1      Col 2     Col 3    Col 4

 Table A | Table B | Table C | 

 Table Z | Table A | Table C | Table Y

 Table K | Table L | Table M | Table B

 Table J | Table H |
```

I have mapped using igraph before but i had a different structure of the data. Just two columns: from & to. Is there a way to graph if I have multiple columns like this? I could not find many resources on this.

I was hoping to create a map. That will have lines that goes from Table A to Table B and C and then another line that goes from Table A to Table z and Table C and Table Y since they are related, etc. Table J and Table H would only have one connection among each other.

http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph. The network in i graph is what I am trying to mimick

Comment: You will need to explain the meaning of your columns.   Does this mean that A, B and C are all completely connected? Also connections between all of Z, A C & Y?   What do you want?  It would also help for you to give us a small sample of your data using `dput(head(df))`

Comment: I edited my post so give more clarification and included a link of what i am trying to do. The columns are  are just a way to know that there is a connection from one to the other. So in the example above A ->B A ->C B->C. The following rows following the same logic. I was hoping to do a network map to get a visualization on which tables connection with others.. Hopefully this is a little clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of another post:

```
plot(graph.data.frame(rbindlist(lapply(seq(ncol(test_a2)-1), function(i) test_a2[i:(i+1)]))))
```

test_a2 is just a dataframe with multiple columns

Here, it will go graph the first two columns then move onto the second and third and so.

I hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence *"So a line going from table A to"* ended abruply, but if it were to end like *both table B and table C"*. Unfortunately, `graph_from_adj_list` only works for numeric lists, so you'll have to just convert your data to a two-column data frame:

You'll need to do some data cleaning. If you're data is in a data frame, then you'll need to use **tidyr**'s `group_by` and `nest` functions, followed by using the `lapply` function to iterate through the new *data* column with the `t` turning the columns into rows:

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)


al_tibble <- tibble(c1 = c('a', 'z', 'k', 'j'),
                    c2 = c('b', 'a', 'l', 'h'),
                    c3 = c('c', 'c', 'h', NA),
                    c4 = c(NA, 'y', 'b', NA))

el <- al %>% 
  group_by(c1) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = lapply(data, t)) %>% 
  unnest() %>%
  filter(!is.na(data))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(el)
```

If your data is organized within a list, then you'll need to iterate through each list item and create a data frame from it. Then you'll need to bind each of the created data frames by using `bind_rows`

```
al_list <- list('a' = c('b', 'c'),
                "z" = c('a', 'c', 'y'),
                "k" = c('l', 'h', 'b'),
                "j" = c('h'))

el2 <- lapply(names(al_list), function(x){
  tibble(from = x,
         to = al_list[[x]])
}) %>%
  bind_rows

g2 <- graph_from_data_frame(el2)
```