# Data frame to network

Tags: r, networking, graph

I have a data frame some columns which are nodes for a network:

| Node1 | Node2 | Node3 | Node4 | Node5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PMDB | PDT | PSDC | PCdob | SD |
| PMDB | PTC | PTN | PRTB | SD |
| PSDB | PPS | PSDC | PDT | PRB |

My expected result would be something like:

| Node1 | Node2 | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PMDB | PDT | 1 |
| PMDB | PSCD | 1 |
| PMDB | PCdoB | 1 |
| PMDB | SD | 2 |
| PSD | PTC | 1 |
| PSD | PTN | 1 |

And so on, considering the interaction of each node.

I tried the following code, unsuccessfully:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(Node1) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = lapply(data, t)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(data))
```

Any help is appreciated. Here follows a reproducible example:

```
structure(list(Node1 = c("DEM ", "PP ", "PMDB ", "PMDB ", "PSTU ", 
"PSD ", "PSDB ", "PSDB ", "PTB ", "PP ", "PP ", "PPL ", "PT do B ", 
"PT ", "PMDB ", "PCB ", "PSOL ", "PT ", "REDE ", "PMDB ", "PP ", 
"PSDB ", "PSOL ", "PSDB ", "PMDB ", "PMDB ", "PSOL ", "PSOL ", 
"PSDB ", "PSD ", "PT ", "PMDB ", "PMDB ", "PROS ", "PSB ", "PDT ", 
"PDT ", "PMDB ", "PRB ", "PSB ", "PMDB ", "PSDB ", "PR ", "PT ", 
"PRTB ", "PDT ", "DEM ", "PSB ", "PT ", "PMDB ", "PSOL ", "PRB ", 
"PR ", "PHS ", "PSDB ", "PHS ", "PSDB ", "PMDB ", "PDT ", "PPS ", 
"PHS ", "PMDB", "PSB ", "PSDB ", "PSB ", "PSD ", "PSB ", "PT ", 
"PTB ", "PDT ", "PSB ", "PMDB ", "PSD ", "PDT ", "PT ", "PSOL ", 
"PMDB ", "PRTB ", "PROS ", "PRB ", "PTB ", "PCB ", "PMDB ", "PP ", 
"PHS ", "PT do B ", "PP ", "PMDB ", "PSOL ", "PMDB ", "PDT ", 
"PSB ", "PSDB ", "PSB ", "PP ", "PT ", "PSOL ", "PP ", "PMDB ", 
"PSOL ", "PSTU ", "DEM ", "PSDB ", "PSOL ", "DEM ", "PSC ", "PT ", 
"PHS ", "PT ", "PHS ", "PV ", "PT ", "PT ", "PSB ", "PTC ", "PT ", 
"DEM ", "MDB ", "PSDB ", "PMN ", "PT ", "PODE ", "PSB ", "PDT ", 
"PODE ", "PSDB ", "PT ", "PSDB ", "REDE ", "MDB ", "PT ", "PR ", 
"PSOL ", "PSD ", "PTC ", "REDE ", "PSDB ", "PSC ", "PRTB ", "PP ", 
"PP ", "REDE ", "PSL ", "PSC ", "PT ", "PDT ", "PC do B ", "PSB ", 
"PT ", "DEM ", "PODE ", "PCB ", "PT ", "PSOL ", "PROS ", "PMN ", 
"PDT ", "REDE ", "PMN ", "PT ", "MDB ", "PSOL ", "PSOL ", "PSOL ", 
"PRB ", "PRB ", "PSB ", "PHS ", "PSD ", "PSOL ", "PSL ", "PSOL ", 
"PRTB ", "PT ", "PT ", "DEM ", "MDB ", "MDB ", "PSOL ", "PMN ", 
"PT ", "SOLIDARIEDADE ", "PC do B ", "PSL ", "PSB ", "REDE ", 
"PMN ", "PSB", "PDT ", "PSL ", "PRP ", "PSDB ", "MDB ", "PSB ", 
"PT ", "PSDB ", "PSD ", "PDT ", "PTB ", "MDB ", "PSOL ", "PSL ", 
"PHS ", "DEM ", "PSB ", "MDB ", "PSOL ", "MDB ", "PR ", "PP ", 
"DEM ", "PSOL ", "PRP ", "PP ", "PT ", "PTB ", "MDB ", "PDT ", 
"PROS ", "PRTB ", "PODE ", "REDE ", "MDB ", "PRB ", "PSDB ", 
"PSDB ", "PSL ", "MDB ", "DEM ", "MDB ", "PSOL ", "PSOL ", "PODE ", 
"PSOL", "PTB ", "PSL ", "PSB ", "PRTB ", "PV ", "DEM ", "PSDB ", 
"PSD ", "PR ", "PDT ", "PSOL ", "PDT ", "PDT ", "PROS "), Node2 = c(" PV ", 
" PDT ", " PTB ", " PC do B ", " PSOL", " PTC ", " DEM ", " PPS ", 
" PT ", " PR ", " SD ", " PMN", " PRB ", " PMDB ", " PT ", " PSTU", 
" PSTU", " PDT ", " PSOL", " PSD ", " PRB ", " PSDC ", " PSTU ", 
" PRB", " PSDB ", " PSDB ", " PSTU", " PMN", " PSD ", " PTC ", 
" PMDB ", " PSB ", " PV ", " PTN ", " PSL ", " PP ", " DEM ", 
" PSC ", " PP ", " SD ", " PSDB ", " PP ", " PPL ", " PV ", " PATRIOTA", 
" PRB ", " PSDB ", " PSC ", " PMDB ", " PROS ", " PSTU ", " PP ", 
" PT do B ", " PRP", " PROS ", " PMN", " PRB", " PT ", " PT ", 
" PP ", " PRP ", NA, " PPL ", " DEM ", " PMN", " PRB ", " PT ", 
" PTC ", " PR ", " AVANTE ", " PT ", " PR ", " PT ", " PT", " PP ", 
" PSTU", " PP ", " PPL ", " DEM ", " PP ", " PR ", " PSTU", " PDT ", 
" PTB ", " PRP ", " PRP ", " PTB ", " DEM ", " PSTU", " PSL ", 
" PSC ", " PMDB ", " PMN ", " PSDC ", " PODE ", " PDT ", " PSTU", 
" PSL ", " PP ", " PSTU", " PCB ", " PSDB ", " PATRIOTA ", " PCB", 
" PSDB ", " PPS ", " PC do B ", " DEM ", " PP ", " PTC ", " PT do B ", 
" PSD ", " PMDB ", " PT ", " PSDB ", " PC do B ", " PRTB ", " PODE ", 
" PTB ", " REDE", " PP ", " PR ", " PDT ", " PROS ", " REDE ", 
" PTB ", " PDT ", " DEM ", " PRTB ", " PP ", " PC do B ", " PSDB ", 
" PCB", " PRB ", " PSDB ", " PPS ", " PTB ", " PRTB ", " REDE ", 
" MDB ", " MDB ", " DC ", " PATRIOTA ", " PROS", " PSOL", " AVANTE", 
" PRB ", " PHS ", " MDB ", " PSDB ", " PMN ", " PSOL ", " PC do B", 
" PCB", " PTB ", " PRB ", " PRP ", " PC do B ", " PATRIOTA", 
" PC do B ", " DC", " PCB", " PCB", " PCB", " PDT ", " PTB ", 
" MDB ", " PR ", " PRB ", " PCB", " PRTB", " PCB", " PSL", " PC do B", 
" PC do B", " REDE ", " PP ", " PSD ", " PCB", " DEM ", " PC do B", 
" PV ", " PT", " PTC ", " PC do B ", " PPL", " PATRIOTA", NA, 
" PP ", " PPS ", " PRTB", " PSD ", " PV ", " PV ", " PC do B ", 
" PSB ", " PSDB ", " PSB", " PMB", " PR ", " PCB", " PRB ", " SOLIDARIEDADE ", 
" PRP ", " PSC ", " PODE ", " PCB", " PATRIOTA ", " PRB ", " PTB ", 
" PSDB ", " PCB", " PRB ", " PDT ", " PC do B", " PPS ", " PRB ", 
" AVANTE ", " PSL", " PRP", " AVANTE ", " PV", " AVANTE ", " PPS ", 
" PROS", " DEM ", " PATRIOTA ", " PDT ", " PP ", " PHS", " PCB", 
" PCB", " PRP ", NA, " PV ", " PRTB", " PDT ", " PSL", " PSDB ", 
" PSD ", " DEM ", " PSC ", " PV ", " PRB ", " PPL ", " PSB ", 
" PODE ", " AVANTE "), Node3 = c(" PMN", " PMDB", " PSDC ", " PSB ", 
NA, " PTN ", " PATRIOTA ", " PSDC", " PSC ", " PPS ", " PROS ", 
NA, " PROS ", " PRB ", " PSD ", NA, NA, " PC do B ", NA, " PPS ", 
" PSDB ", " PSD ", " PCB", NA, " PSB ", " PT do B ", NA, NA, 
" PSB ", " PTN ", " PC do B ", " PT do B ", " PPL", " PPL ", 
" PPL", " DEM ", " PV ", " DEM ", " PDT ", " PDT ", " DEM ", 
" DEM ", " PROS ", " PSB ", NA, " PT ", " PP ", " PRP", " PROS ", 
" PSD ", " PCB", " PDT ", " PROS", NA, " DEM ", NA, NA, " DEM ", 
" PSL ", " PSDC ", " PPS ", NA, " PRTB", " PSD ", NA, " PMDB ", 
" PDT ", " PC do B ", " DEM ", " PATRIOTA ", " PSOL ", " PSB ", 
" PC do B ", NA, " PSD ", NA, " PT ", " PMN", " PSL ", " PDT ", 
" DEM ", NA, " PSB ", " DEM", " PPS ", " PHS ", " DEM", " SD ", 
NA, " PATRIOTA ", " DEM ", " PSDB ", " SD ", " PSL ", " PT do B", 
" PC do B ", NA, " PTN ", " PSC ", NA, " PSOL", " PMDB ", " PR ", 
NA, " SD ", " PRTB ", " PR", " PTC ", " PTB ", " PRTB ", " PMDB ", 
" PC do B ", " PSD ", " PTB ", " PP ", " PHS", " PV", " PPS ", 
" PP ", NA, " PDT ", " REDE ", " PT ", " PTB ", " DC ", " PRB ", 
" PP ", " MDB ", " PTB ", " AVANTE ", " PSB ", " DEM ", NA, " PPS ", 
" PP ", " PRP", " PSB ", " REDE", " PODE ", " PSDB ", " DC ", 
" PPL", " PSC", NA, NA, NA, " PDT ", " PROS ", " PP ", " PDT ", 
" PMB ", " PSTU", NA, NA, " PHS ", " SOLIDARIEDADE ", " AVANTE ", 
" PV", NA, " PROS", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PT ", " PR ", " PR ", " PSL", 
" PDT ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSDB ", " PRB ", " PSB ", 
NA, " PP ", NA, " DC ", NA, " PATRIOTA", " PT ", NA, NA, NA, 
" MDB ", " PSB ", NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE ", " PSD ", " PC do B ", 
" PROS", " DEM", " DEM ", NA, NA, " DC ", NA, " PTC ", " PP ", 
" PROS ", " PPS ", " PMN ", NA, " PR", " PSL", " DEM ", " PSC ", 
NA, " PTC ", " PODE ", NA, " PSDB ", " PHS ", " PV ", NA, NA, 
" PATRIOTA ", NA, " PSDB ", " PSC ", NA, " PSD ", " PPL", " SOLIDARIEDADE ", 
" MDB ", NA, NA, NA, " PSC ", NA, " REDE ", NA, " PPL ", NA, 
" PP ", " PDT ", " PSD ", " PV ", " PRB ", " PODE", " PCB", " PTB ", 
" MDB ", " PDT"), Node4 = c(NA, NA, " PC do B ", " PTC ", NA, 
" PATRIOTA ", " PMN ", NA, " PDT ", " PROS ", " PSDB ", NA, " PR ", 
" PC do B ", " PV", NA, NA, " PV ", NA, " PSB ", " SD", " PATRIOTA ", 
NA, NA, " PRB ", " PSC ", NA, NA, " PP ", " PATRIOTA ", " PROS ", 
" PSC ", NA, " PMN ", NA, " PSDB ", " PSDB ", " PSDC ", " PT ", 
" PSD", " SD ", " PSD ", " SD ", " PC do B", NA, " PSL ", " PT do B ", 
NA, " PR ", " PP ", NA, " PTB ", NA, NA, " PSB ", NA, NA, " PR ", 
" PR ", " PRP ", " PPL ", NA, NA, " SD ", NA, " PR ", " DEM ", 
" PROS ", " PRTB ", " PSD ", " PC do B", " PROS ", " PT do B ", 
NA, " PDT ", NA, " PDT ", NA, " PTN ", " PTB ", " PRTB ", NA, 
" PTN ", NA, " PPL ", " PATRIOTA", NA, " PC do B ", NA, " PSDC ", 
" PV ", " PR ", " DEM ", " PP ", NA, " PRB ", NA, " PPS ", " PTB ", 
NA, NA, " SD ", " PTB ", NA, " PSD", " PMN ", NA, " PRB ", " PHS ", 
" PATRIOTA ", " PROS ", " PRTB ", " PP ", " Pode ", " PSB ", 
NA, NA, " PDT ", " PR ", NA, " PSD ", " PPL", " DEM ", " MDB ", 
" PHS ", " PPS ", " PSB ", " PSD ", " PC do B ", " PSL ", " DC ", 
" DC", NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE ", " PSB ", NA, " PR ", NA, " MDB ", 
" DEM ", " PC do B ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PPS ", " PV ", " PR ", 
" PSB ", " PSB ", NA, NA, NA, " PATRIOTA ", " PPL ", " PP ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PODE ", " PPS ", " PODE ", NA, 
" PSB ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PPL ", " PR ", " PR ", NA, 
" PSB ", NA, " PSC ", NA, NA, " MDB ", NA, NA, NA, " PODE ", 
" DC ", NA, " PTB ", " PSC ", " PDT ", NA, NA, " PRB ", NA, NA, 
" PRTB ", NA, " PRP ", " DEM ", " PMN ", " PTB ", " PSC ", NA, 
NA, NA, " PMN ", " PTB ", NA, " PATRIOTA", " PRTB ", NA, " DEM ", 
" PP", " PODE ", NA, NA, " REDE ", NA, " PTB ", " PR ", NA, " PRB ", 
NA, " PC do B", " PTB ", NA, NA, NA, " PTC", NA, " PT", NA, " PTB ", 
NA, " PSD ", " PSC ", " PRB ", " PR ", " PT ", NA, NA, " DC ", 
" PROS ", NA), Node5 = c(NA, NA, " SD ", " PRP ", NA, " PRTB ", 
" PT do B ", NA, " PRB ", " PV ", " PC do B ", NA, " PATRIOTA ", 
" PRP ", NA, NA, NA, " PTC", NA, " PHS ", NA, " PHS ", NA, NA, 
" PDT ", " PTC ", NA, NA, " SD ", " PRTB ", " PRB", " PHS ", 
NA, " PSDC ", NA, " PSB ", " PSD ", " PRP ", " PTB ", NA, " PATRIOTA ", 
" PTB ", " PMB", NA, NA, " PTN ", " PSC ", NA, " PC do B", " PDT", 
NA, " PSL ", NA, NA, " PSD ", NA, NA, " PDT ", " PSDC ", " PR ", 
" PSB ", NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, " PTB ", " PRTB ", " PPL ", " PMN", 
" PSC", NA, " PDT ", " PP ", NA, " PR ", NA, " PTB ", NA, " PSC ", 
" PSL ", " PMN", NA, " PTB ", NA, " PSB ", NA, NA, " PRTB ", 
NA, " PRP ", " PATRIOTA", " PRB ", " PATRIOTA ", " PRTB ", NA, 
" PTN", NA, " PRTB ", " PSL ", NA, NA, " PTN ", " PSD ", NA, 
NA, " PTC ", NA, " PMN ", " PR ", " PMB", " PC do B ", " PDT ", 
" PR ", " PC do B", " PSC ", NA, NA, " PR ", " DEM ", NA, " PSB ", 
NA, " PTB ", " DC ", " PMN ", " PHS ", " PR ", " PPS ", " PT ", 
" PPL", " PR", NA, NA, " PODE ", " PSC ", NA, " PSD ", NA, " PMN ", 
" PSD ", " PSD ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " DEM ", " PSC ", " PDT ", 
" SOLIDARIEDADE ", " PROS", NA, NA, NA, " PMN ", " PTC", " PV ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PROS ", " PMB ", " PSC ", NA, " PODE ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PP ", " PSC ", " PSC ", NA, " PTB ", 
NA, " PSL ", NA, NA, " PP ", NA, NA, NA, " DEM", " PRP ", NA, 
" PPS ", " PMB ", " REDE", NA, NA, " PTC ", NA, NA, " PHS ", 
NA, " PROS ", " PTC ", " PMB ", " PV ", " PC do B ", NA, NA, 
NA, " PMB ", " PRB ", NA, NA, " PR ", NA, " PSC ", NA, " PPL ", 
NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, " PTC ", " PTC ", NA, " PATRIOTA", NA, NA, 
" SOLIDARIEDADE ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PROS ", NA, 
" PSC ", " MDB ", " PP ", " PRB ", " PTB ", NA, NA, " PP ", " PRB ", 
NA), Node6 = c(NA, NA, " PR", " PV ", NA, " SD", " PTC ", NA, 
" PT do B", " PTC", " PSB ", NA, " PV ", " PPL ", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, " PT do B ", NA, " PSC ", NA, NA, " PSL ", " PPS ", NA, 
NA, " PRB ", " SD", NA, " PRB ", NA, " PC do B ", NA, " PPS ", 
" PRB ", " PSDB ", " PSL ", NA, " PROS ", " PPS ", NA, NA, NA, 
" PSDC ", " PTC ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSC ", NA, NA, " PTB ", 
NA, NA, " PROS ", " PV ", " PSL ", " PSL", NA, NA, " PMN", NA, 
" PSC ", " PRP ", " PTB ", NA, NA, NA, " SD ", " PATRIOTA ", 
NA, " PC do B ", NA, " PPS ", NA, " PR ", " PR ", NA, NA, " PC do B ", 
NA, " PSL", NA, NA, " PTN ", NA, " PTN ", NA, " PSD ", " PTN ", 
" PT do B ", NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", " PPS ", NA, NA, " PROS ", 
" SD ", NA, NA, " PRP ", NA, " PP ", " PROS ", NA, " PSC ", " PRP ", 
" PROS ", NA, " PROS ", NA, NA, " PTB ", " SOLIDARIEDADE ", NA, 
" PC do B ", NA, " PRP ", " PRB ", " PSDB", " REDE ", " PTB ", 
" SOLIDARIEDADE ", " PV ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSC", " PROS ", 
NA, " PPS ", NA, " PATRIOTA", " PTB ", " PT ", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, " PSB ", " AVANTE ", " PSD ", " PRP ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PTC ", 
NA, " PR ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PC do B ", " PTC ", 
" PSDB", NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSC ", 
" PTB ", " PATRIOTA ", NA, " PSDB ", NA, " PATRIOTA", NA, NA, 
" PR ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSDB ", NA, " PMN ", " PRP", NA, NA, 
NA, " PATRIOTA", NA, NA, " PRP", NA, " PSC ", " PRB ", " PSC ", 
" PR ", " PHS ", NA, NA, NA, " PSB ", " SOLIDARIEDADE ", NA, 
NA, " PHS ", NA, " PRB ", NA, " PMB ", NA, NA, " PV ", NA, " PRTB ", 
" PSDB ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSDB ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" PRP", NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE ", " PMB ", " PTC", " PHS ", " PODE ", 
NA, NA, " PR ", " PV", NA), Node7 = c(NA, NA, NA, " PTN ", NA, 
NA, " PTN ", NA, NA, NA, " PDT ", NA, " PHS ", " PV ", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, " PSL ", NA, " PMN ", NA, NA, " PTN ", " PR ", NA, 
NA, " PSC ", NA, NA, " PRTB ", NA, " PT do B", NA, " PV ", " PSC", 
" PR ", " PRTB ", NA, " PRP", " PV ", NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", " PSL ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, " PR ", NA, NA, " PP ", NA, NA, " PHS ", " PROS ", 
" PSB ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSDC ", " PV ", " PR", NA, NA, 
NA, " PSC ", " PRTB ", NA, " PTB ", NA, " PRB ", NA, " PRTB ", 
" PPS ", NA, NA, " PRTB ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PPL", NA, " PMN ", 
NA, " SD ", " PTB ", " PPS ", NA, NA, NA, " PTC ", " PTN ", NA, 
NA, " PRB ", " PMN ", NA, NA, " PPL ", NA, " PPS", " PRP ", NA, 
" PHS ", " PROS ", " PDT ", NA, " PRB ", NA, NA, " PHS ", " PPS ", 
NA, " PR ", NA, " PODE ", " PRP ", NA, " PP", " DEM ", " DC", 
" PDT ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PRB ", NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE ", 
NA, NA, " PMN ", " PHS", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PR ", " PTC ", 
" PC do B ", " PMN ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PMB", NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSB ", " PSB ", NA, NA, " PROS ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " AVANTE ", " PHS ", " PRP ", NA, " PATRIOTA ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, " PMN ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PATRIOTA ", NA, " PSC ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PPL ", " AVANTE ", " DC ", 
" PODE ", " PROS ", NA, NA, NA, " PSDB ", " PV ", NA, NA, " PC do B", 
NA, " PV ", NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE", NA, NA, " PRP ", NA, " DC ", 
" SOLIDARIEDADE", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, " DC ", " PHS ", NA, " PPS ", " PMN ", NA, NA, 
" SOLIDARIEDADE ", NA, NA), Node8 = c(NA, NA, NA, " PR ", NA, 
NA, " SD ", NA, NA, NA, " PTC ", NA, " PSDC ", " PP ", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, " PSDC", NA, " PT do B ", NA, NA, " PPS ", " SD ", 
NA, NA, " PTB ", NA, NA, " PTN ", NA, NA, NA, " PTB ", NA, " PTN ", 
" PHS ", NA, NA, " PDT ", NA, NA, NA, " PSB ", " PTB ", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, NA, " PC do B ", " PC do B ", 
" DEM ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PROS ", " PSL ", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" PTB ", " PTC", NA, " PMN", NA, " PSDC ", NA, " PHS ", " PHS ", 
NA, NA, " PSL ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSC ", NA, " PROS ", 
" PTC ", " PR ", NA, NA, NA, " PSB ", " DEM ", NA, NA, " PSC ", 
" PPS ", NA, NA, " PTB", NA, NA, " SD", NA, " PTB ", " PSDC ", 
" PC do B ", NA, " DEM", NA, NA, " PT ", " PRB ", NA, " PMB ", 
NA, " PRB ", " PC do B ", NA, NA, " PC do B ", NA, " PSD", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, " DEM", NA, " PV ", NA, NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PP ", " PPS ", " PTB ", " PRTB ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PV ", 
" PRP ", NA, NA, " PSC ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSD ", " PODE ", 
" PMN ", NA, " PSD ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PTC ", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" AVANTE ", NA, " DEM ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" PATRIOTA", " PATRIOTA ", " PSL ", " PMB ", " PV", NA, NA, NA, 
" PROS", " PPL", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PODE ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PHS", 
NA, " PR ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PV ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, " PRTB ", " PTC", NA, " PODE ", " PC do B ", NA, 
NA, " PTC", NA, NA), Node9 = c(NA, NA, NA, " PSD ", NA, NA, " PPS ", 
NA, NA, NA, " PPS", NA, " PTN", " PTN ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, " PRB ", NA, NA, " DEM ", " PP ", NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, 
NA, " PATRIOTA", NA, NA, NA, " PSDC ", NA, " PPS", " PMN ", NA, 
NA, " PR ", NA, NA, NA, " PRP ", " SD ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " DEM ", 
NA, NA, " PSC ", NA, NA, " PSL ", " PTB ", " SD", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, " PV ", " PC do B ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, " PPL ", NA, " PTC ", " PMN ", NA, NA, " PRP", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", NA, " PPS ", " PT do B", " PSC ", NA, 
NA, NA, " PSDB ", " PSDC ", NA, NA, " PTC ", " PT do B ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSD ", " PMDB ", " PRB", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, " PV ", " PSD", NA, " PRP ", NA, " PC do B ", " PMB", NA, 
NA, " PPS ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " AVANTE ", 
NA, NA, " PTC ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PROS ", " PSDB ", 
" PRTB", " PPS", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PTB ", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSOL ", " PSDB ", NA, NA, " PC do B ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PODE ", " PMB ", " PTC", NA, " PPS ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, " PRP ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE", NA, " PP ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PROS", " PODE ", " PHS ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PRTB ", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, " PPS", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " DC ", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", NA, NA, " AVANTE", " PROS ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Node10 = c(NA, NA, NA, " PPS ", NA, NA, " PRB ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PT do B ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, " DEM", NA, NA, " PSDC ", " PSD", NA, NA, " PATRIOTA ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSC ", NA, NA, " PTC ", NA, NA, " PMN ", 
NA, NA, NA, " PATRIOTA ", " PV ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PRTB ", NA, 
NA, " PR ", NA, NA, " PPL ", " PTC ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" PC do B ", " PHS ", NA, NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" PC do B", NA, " PV ", " PTC ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, " PRTB ", NA, " PSC ", NA, " PSD ", NA, NA, NA, " PATRIOTA ", 
" PHS ", NA, NA, " PV ", " PTN ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" PDT ", " PSB ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PRP ", NA, NA, " PODE ", 
NA, " AVANTE ", NA, NA, NA, " PRP ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, " REDE", NA, NA, " PR ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
" PT ", " DEM ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", " PSD ", NA, NA, " PHS ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " SOLIDARIEDADE", " DC ", NA, NA, " AVANTE ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, " PATRIOTA ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PTC ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PTC ", " PPL ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PSL ", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PHS ", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, " PTC ", NA, NA, NA, " PP", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -248L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the Weight column supposed to represent?

Comment: Hi, the number of times a node connects to another. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could create a network adapting a code form this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908208/network-map-from-multiple-columns) using:

```
library(data.table)
c3 <- rbindlist(lapply(seq(ncol(c2) - 1), function(i) c2[i:(i+1)])) 
c3 <- c3 |> 
  na.omit()
```

The final result was something like:

```
structure(list(Node1 = c("DEM ", "PP ", "PMDB ", "PMDB ", "PSTU "
), Node2 = c(" PV ", " PDT ", " PTB ", " PC do B ", " PSOL")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb62d00f6e0>)
```

If anyone gets a better solution, I will be happy to withdraw the answer and reformulate my code.

Thanks